# Can't get wait-job result

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to achieve this with a code:

- ☑ Run a command
- ☑ Wait X seconds
- ☐ If command completed and is successful i return 1
- ☐ If command completed and is not successful i return 0
- ☑ If command did not completed I return 0.

I don't need it to be asynchronous. This is my first code:

```
$timeoutSeconds = 10
$code = {
    ping something
}
$job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock $code
if (Wait-Job $job -Timeout $timeoutSeconds) { Receive-Job $job }
Remove-Job -force $job

if ($job.State -eq 'Completed'){
    $ExitCode = 0
}
else {
    $ExitCode = 1
}
```

My Powershell

```
[System.Environment]::OSVersion.Version

Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
6      2      9200   0
```

I would like this to be not only for my powershell version.

I tried to add a return inside my `$code`

```
$code = {
    ping something
    return $LASTEXITCODE
}
```

But I can't find anything inside my `$job`.
I tried to assign `Receive-Job` to a variable, but it doesn't get never populated.

```
if (Wait-Job $job -Timeout $timeoutSeconds) { $r = Receive-Job $job }
```

`$r` is alwasys empty (in both cases: Wait-Job reach or not the timeout).

I want to get the `$LASTEXITCODE` i'm returning in my `$code` block, I would like something like:

```
$timeoutSeconds = 10
$code = {
    ping 2.3.1.2
    return $LASTEXITCODE
}
$job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock $code
if (Wait-Job $job -Timeout $timeoutSeconds) { Receive-Job $job }
Remove-Job -force $job

if ($job.State -eq 'Completed'){
    $ExitCode = $job.ReturnedValue #this doesn't exists
}
else {
    $ExitCode = 1
}

Write-Output $ExitCode
```

My problem is how to discern if:

- Job completed in less than timeout because it succeeded
- Job completed in less than timeout because it failed faster than I thought.

The command I'm running is a software command I would like to leave unkown, it is a something like a ping but:

1. the command finish in less than 10 seconds when it works (return 0)
2. the command finish in more than 10 seconds (30 or more) when the resource is unreachable (return 1)
3. the command finish in less than 10 seconds when something went wrong (return 1)

If the case is `2` the job is not completed.
If the case is either `1` or `2` I need the returned value inside the `$code` block to understand if the command is good or not.

How do I get the returned value inside the `$code` block outside after the job is completed? (if job is not completed I'm aware I can't have it, but I should be able to use the result of a job)

Thanks

Comment: What are you expecting ```Receive-Job``` to return? Also, can you replace ```MyCommands``` with some sample code that reproduces the issue (.e.g. simply return a value or add a sleep)? It's difficult to comment on what the problem might be if we're unable to see it on our own screens...

Comment: Sorry, I update the question, there is no actual error btw.

Comment: It's not at all clear what the problem is here... Does `$ExitCode` have an unexpected value after you run this? And why are you calling `Receive-Job` at all? "Fetch output from job" is not in your list of things the script should do...

Comment: I added some information. But my problem is to get the returned value from the command inside the job. I'm calling `Receive-Job` because I want to retrieve from the `$job` the returned value in some way... I'm trying thing and actually thet command could be totally useless, I don't know.

Comment: If you're making a lot of jobs, you might install the threadjob module which is faster and only uses one process.

Answer (score 1):

If `Wait-Job -Timeout <timeoutInSeconds>` returns the job object then you know the job completed in time. If a terminating error occurred that caused the job to exit prematurely, the `State` property on the job object will reflect this, so simply do:

```
$timeoutSeconds = 10
$completedInTime = $false
$code = {
  MyCommands
}

# start job, wait for timeout
$job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock $code
if($job |Wait-Job -Timeout $timeoutSeconds){
  # If it completed successfully, State will have the value `Completed`
  $completedInTime = $job.State -eq 'Completed'
  $results = $job |Receive-Job
}

$job |Remove-Job -Force

# `$true` = 1
# `$false` = 0
$ExitCode = [int]$completedInTime
```

Comment: what if the job complete in less than 10 seconds but the actual command in `$code` has an exit code of 1 (error) ? If you put `ping 2.1.23.1 /n 1` in the `$code` block, you will surely have that job completed in time, but my question was about having a response about the actual command response code. the `$LASTEXITCODE` of ping 2.1.23.1 would be 1, hence, my `$ExitCode` should be 1 for failure.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Mathias R. Jessen I achieved this:

```
$timeoutSeconds = 10
$completedInTime = $false
$code = {
  ping 2.13.1.2 /n 1 > null # this way results won't have this output that I don't need
  return $LASTEXITCODE
}

# start job, wait for timeout
$job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock $code
if($job |Wait-Job -Timeout $timeoutSeconds){
  # If it completed successfully, State will have the value `Completed`
  if($job.State -eq 'Completed'){
      # Only in this case results will hold the LASTEXITCODE I returned in code block
      $results = $job |Receive-Job
      if ($results -eq 0){
          $ExitCode = 0
      }
      else {
          $ExitCode = 1
     }
  }
  else{
    # In this case I know the command is failing
    $ExitCode = 1
  }
}

$job |Remove-Job -Force
Write-Output $ExitCode
```